# kernel not mounting rootfs ext4

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ext4, embedded

I have a machine that has an ext4 partition as the rootfs. The kernel is placed in another partition. After some time the kernel printed a panic because the rootfs was corrupted. After running fsck it booted as expected. My question is why the kernel did not try to recover the file system and why this kind of error happens, although ext4 is power resilient. What are the reasons that ext4 is corrupted and it makes the kernel unable to mount the rootfs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The kernel did not try to recover the file system because system must be configured for that. On unixlike systems users may have different filesystems (luks,raid,btrfs,zfs,etc...), which configuration and behavior significantly differs from each other. So default behavior in many distros is configured to be harmless for the data stored on disks. The reason of filesystem corruption can be different. Worst case is hardware malfuncion.

In your system `tune2fs` command can trigger a forced fsck on every reboot using the -c (max-mount-counts) option. This option sets the number of mounts after which the filesystem will be checked, so setting it to 1 will run fsck each time the computer boots. Setting it to -1 or 0 resets this (the number of times the filesystem is mounted will be disregarded by e2fsck and the kernel).

```
sudo tune2fs -c 1 /dev/sdXY
```

For this to work you'll need to make sure the partition you want to check and repair using fsck has the pass number greater than 0 set in `/etc/fstab` (last column in /etc/fstab). The root partition should be set to 1 (first to be checked), while other partitions you want to be checked should be set to 2.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
/dev/sda1  /      ext4  errors=remount-ro  0  1
/dev/sda5  /home  ext4  defaults           0  2
```

Also you need to add `fsck.repair=yes` as a kernel parameter to your bootloader configuration to enable automtical fs **repair** without user intervention.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea why the filesystem was corrupted besides hardware problem?